# Continuous webjob keeps restarting itself

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a long-running continuous web job in a web app which is set for "Always On" and is hosted in *Premium: 1 Medium* service plan. Still I see sometimes my web jobs restart because of website shut down. Here is the log:

```
[05/17/2016 23:01:43 > feb726: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running

[05/18/2016 03:15:59 > feb726: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down

[05/18/2016 03:15:59 > feb726: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping

[05/18/2016 03:16:02 > feb726: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
```

Comment: a) are you sure the webjob is attached to an Web App with 'AlwaysOn' enabled? b) does the Web App periodically cause the app pool to restart due a leak or some feature in the web app? c) when you do a new deployment to the Web App this is going to happen as the new deployment causes an App Pool recycle.

Comment: Yes to "Always On".
Good pointer in point b. I will check that.
About point c:  We deploy with the web job stopped (adding disable.job file). Hence, I assume, the app pool would have copied the files already due to deployment. Now, just when I start the job, it restarts itself after running for few seconds. Is that expected?

Comment: Can you clarify "keeps restarting itself"? What kind of frequency? Are we talking constantly, or once every few days?

Comment: @DavidEbbo, it restarts every couple of hours. I have checked, its not a memory leak. process memory is reaching only 600MB in an app service plan of 7GB ram.

Comment: Can you share the site name? You can do it indirectly if you like https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: @Purbasha. The logs say that the website is restarting because of which webjob also restarts. Have you defined any triggers on the website which restarts the website?Check if you have defined any [triggers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/) on your website

Comment: Did you even found a solution/reason? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Even i am facing same problem.